# How to increase performance on ASP.NET/IIS/SQL website

Tags: iis, asp.net, sql, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a small internal ASP.NET website running on IIS8 and SQL2014 express.

The server is an onsite dedicated server 2012 R2 VM that has both IIS and SQL server on it.

The server CPU usage rarely gets over 25%, the memory usage sits at 50% and the disk barely moves.

However web pages can sometimes be very slow, and some queries can take multiple seconds to do anything, and this is starting to frustrate my users (clicking on an edit link can take 10 seconds in some cases before the textbox appears).

As the server doesn't seem to be being utilised can anyone point me in the right direction as to where to start looking for performance enhancements?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, make sure you're metrics are being gathered correctly.  In a virtual environment you can't necessarily rely on traditional performance counters.  The host can (and will)  regulate hardware allocations to your VM based its load and the demands of other VM's it's managing.

There is not much to go on from your question in the way of details, but here are some general pointers.

- SQL Server Express is capped at 1 GB of RAM.  That could be a good deal of your pain right there.  See the [**SQL Server edition comparison**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) for more limits.
- Look at the load from the host server.  Are other VM's running?  What are they doing?
- What is your hypervisor?  How is it tuned?
- Take a deep dive into your application and see how it's behaving when interacting with SQL Server.  Often times performance issues are due to poorly written queries.  Fire up SQL Profiler or do a trace to see what queries are coming in.  Do some monitoring to find offenders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The server has been assigned 4Gb of RAM, SQL is using about 600Mb so far, so it doesn't seem to be hitting up against the 1Gb limit, the one and only database is about 400mb. The load from the host server is minimal, i've moved all other VM's off the host to see if it makes a difference it doesn't. The Hypervisor is ESXi (free version). Your last point is where i'm at at the moment, but to be honest nothing is coming to light as "ahh! theres the problem!"

Answer (score 1):

Debugging? Seriously.

> and some queries can take multiple seconds to do anything

Grab them, analyze them. Would not be the first time that a programmer not really knowing what he does or not having a real load scenario in mind (or available for testing) is missing indices that get critical under production load.

Nothing you can do as sys admin in this case - this is something the programmer side must fix.

Please also measure disc latency because that may be a culprit - but generally: start profiling, doing a load test (on a separate system) and figuring out code wise which part is fast.

THAT SAID: also consider running your site access through cloudflare and have them cache - that may give a faster user experience.